# How to send a custom Solr Query using Search API Solr

Tags: search

I'd like to send custom solr query (preferably in hook_init) using Search API Solr to a specific URL.

Something like:

```
function hook_init() {
  $url = "admin/luke?show=schema";
  $solr = new SearchApiSolrService(); // must have an instance of SearchApiServer
  // $httpTransport->performHeadRequest($url);
  // $response = _sendRawGet($url);
  drupal_set_message(print_r($response, TRUE));
}
```

How I can do achieve that? Is there any live example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From version RC4 you can use makeServletRequest() to generate custom solr queries. See some [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22%3D+makeServletRequest%22&type=Code).

Here are some code examples:

```
  // Ping example
  // class_exists('Apache_Solr_Service') ?: spl_autoload_register('_search_api_solr_autoload'); // make sure that SolrPhpClient class is loaded (use only for <=rc3)
  $server = search_api_server_load('my_solr_server'); // CHANGE THIS
  $solr = new SearchApiSolrService($server);
  $result = $solr->ping();
  drupal_set_message(print_r($result, TRUE));

  // Simple search query (not fully tested)
  // class_exists('Apache_Solr_Service') ?: spl_autoload_register('_search_api_solr_autoload'); // make sure that SolrPhpClient class is loaded (use only for <=rc3)
  $server = search_api_server_load('my_solr_server'); // CHANGE THIS
  $index = search_api_index_load('my_index'); // CHANGE THIS
  $query = new SearchApiQuery($index);
  $query->keys('foo'); 
  $query->fields(array('title')); 
  $solr = new SearchApiSolrService($server);
  $result = $solr->search($query);
  drupal_set_message(print_r($result, TRUE));

  // Custom path example for rc4 and above (not fully tested)
  $server = search_api_server_load('my_solr_server');
  $uri = SearchApiSolrConnection::LUKE_SERVLET . "?show=schema"; // or any other custom URL
  $connection = $server->getSolrConnection(); // or: new SearchApiSolrService($server)
  $response = $connection->makeServletRequest($uri);
  drupal_set_message(print_r($response, TRUE));

  // Example for assembling the right URL
  $server = search_api_server_load('my_solr_server');
  $url = 'http://' . $server->options['host'] . ':' . $server->options['port'] . $server->options['path'];
```

Above code tested in hook_init with [Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/drupal) and [Search API Solr [rc3]](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr).

---

**Acquia**

If you're using Acquia, you can use [Acquia-Search-Proxy](https://github.com/timhilliard/Acquia-Search-Proxy) which allows you to send custom queries against Acquia Search (Apachesolr + Search API Solr). See also my fork of [Acquia-Search-Proxy](https://github.com/kenorb/Acquia-Search-Proxy) which include some extra improvements.

Example custom queries via CLI:

```
PATH_INFO="/admin/ping" php search-proxy.php
PATH_INFO="/admin/luke" QUERY_STRING="show=schema" php search-proxy.php
PATH_INFO="/select" QUERY_STRING="q=foo" php search-proxy.php
PATH_INFO="/admin/file" QUERY_STRING="contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml" php search-proxy.php
```

Answer (score 6):

I've seen an example in a presentation at http://nickveenhof.github.io/devdays_solr_wizardry/#/click-recipes-search-api. I don't understand every line of code (I mean - why does he add a 'bundle' filter and remove it again?) but I still hope it helps.

```
$solr = apachesolr_get_solr();
$query = apachesolr_drupal_query("custom", array('q' => 'mykeys'), 'sort_label asc', 'search/path');
$query->setSolrsort('sort_name', 'desc');
$query->addFilter('bundle', (article OR page));
$query->removeFilter('bundle');
$query->addParam('fq', "bundle:(article OR page)");
$query->addParam('fq', "field_date:[1970-12-31T23:59:59Z TO NOW]");
$resp = $query->search();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's good, but unfortunately it's for Apachesolr, not by using Search API Solr.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I don't have a code example for Search API, but it looks like the documentation at http://drupal.org/node/2004270 and the inline documentation in [query.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/search_api.git/blob/HEAD:/includes/query.inc), especially the SearchApiQuery class, is pretty detailed.

Answer (score 2):

SearchApiQuery offers a pretty complete tool to build custom queries.

Some code example :

```
  global $language;
  $term = 'TERM_TO_SEARCH_IN_THE_TITLE';

  // Select an index.      
  $index = search_api_index_load("default_multilingual_node_index");
  $query = new SearchApiQuery($index);

  // Build a filter.
  $filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
  $filter->condition('type', 'article', '=');
  $filter->condition('type', 'blog_post', '=');
  $query->filter($filter);

  // Conditions.
  $query->condition('title_field', $term, '=');
  $query->condition('language', $language->language, '=');
  $query->sort('timestamp_field');

  // Fetch results.
  $results = $query->execute()['results'];
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to add facets to your query, use setOption

```
$query = new SearchApiQuery($index);
$query->keys(''); 
$query->range(0,0); 
$query->fields(array());
$query->setOption('search_api_facets',array(array('field'=>'field_country'))); 
$solr = new SearchApiSolrService($server);
$result = $solr->search($query);
```