# How to send a custom Solr Distance Query with SearchApi

Tags: 8, location, search

My nodes have a geofield and my search query should find all the nodes within a range.

I've managed to create a search form against my Solr Server with views. But I want to do the request by myself (having my own form and submit method). There's a solution for D7 here: [How to send a custom Solr Query using Search API Solr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74505/how-to-send-a-custom-solr-query-using-search-api-solr) but none of that seems to be usable with the D8 modules.

I believe there must be something like

```
$result = SolrSearchService('myServer', 'myIndex')->request(['title' => 'Test']);
```

But I can not find anything.

The views-built search page renders a query against my Solr Server like

```
path=/select params={q=(phonm_rendered_item:nintendo^1+tm_title:nintendo^8)&json.nl=flat&pt=48.1371079,11.5753822&d=50&omitHeader=true&fl=ss_search_api_id,ss_search_api_language,score,fts_field_geo_koordinaten__distance:geodist()&start=0&fq=%2Bindex_id:default_solr_index+%2Bhash:ozztjn&fq={!geofilt}&rows=10&sfield=locs_field_geo_koordinaten&wt=json}
```

Apparently there are some parameters responsible for the distance calculation:

- pt=48.1371079,11.5753822 - it's where I am
- d=50 - it's the max distance
- field_geo_koordinaten - it's the geofield in the node
- geodist() - the function ?

How can I render such a query with Search API?

Comment: Are you using the search API module with solr? if so this might help https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/developer-documentation/executing-a-search-in-code

Comment: Thanks, Leigh. I am using Search API and  Solr Search - and I am already testing some approaches with the code in your link. But it seems to be pretty difficult.

Comment: Thanks again, I got it working with your link. Now I am puzzling with my geofield and search radius. I will change the question.

Comment: I have some examples I can post later. You can leverage SearchAPI to some extent - or use the Solarium client directly.

Comment: Here is a very very basic example: https://gist.github.com/kevinquillen/cad07541347385744b161a26690ab75d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging around I found the solution:

```
$index = Index::load('default_solr_index');
/* @var \Drupal\search_api\Query\Query $query */
$query = $index->query();
$query->keys($form_state->getValue("keys"));
$location_options = (array) $query->getOption('search_api_location', []);

$location_options[] = [
      'field' => "field_geo_koordinaten",
      'lat' => 48.1371079,
      'lon' => 11.5753822,
      'radius' => 50,
    ];

$query->setOption('search_api_location', $location_options);
$results = $query->execute();
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.